# How to set space around cells in WPF ListView + GridView?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to replace DataGrid with ListView + GridView. Unfortunately it looks completely different and I don't understand enough about styles to make all changes. I got column header figured out but the styles for cells is trickier to implement.

EDIT: THIS QUESTION IS ESSENTIALLY SAME AS "HOW CAN I GET VERTICAL GRIDLINES?" BECAUSE I GAN GET SPACE BETWEEN ROWS BY USING MARGIN. SO IT SEEMS THAT MICROSOFT FORGOT THE MOST IMPORTANT FEATURE IN THEIR GRIDVIEW: THE ONE THAT MAKES IT A GRID.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.UI.Dialogs.SomeWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="{DynamicResource Theme.TreeView.Background}">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" >
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.FontWeight}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.Cell.Padding}"/>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Background}"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Theme.DataGrid.ColumnHeader.Foreground}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" >
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.BorderThickness}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Row.Foreground}" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{DynamicResource Theme.DataGrid.Cell.Padding}"></Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView >
          <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Age"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Mail"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="Group"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Group}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

So how to set space around each cell (e.g. 2 on each side)?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as soon as you use `DisplayMemberBinding`, everything else (including CellStyles) is completely ignored. What you can (and probably have to) do is define all your columns manually, e.g.:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Name">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Details about styling/template priority [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding.aspx):

> The following properties are all used to define the content and style of a column cell, and are listed here in their order of precedence, from highest to lowest:
>
> - DisplayMemberBinding
> - CellTemplate
> - CellTemplateSelector

---

Can can theoretically style every single ListItem like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,0"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But unfortunately that would simply misalign all columns, so this approach is not really useful for Margin/Padding.

[image: Misaligned Columns]

Comment: thanks for your answer. this question was originally asked badly. see my edit. what I really need is vertical gridlines. i meant that each cell has space on both right and left and the underlying color (e.g. gray) is shown aligned with column borders. so i want gridview to work like it should: a grid.

Comment: @charm Oooooh, I was focusing on the actual question (*"So how to set space around each cell (e.g. 2 on each side)?"*). I'm afraid you are going to have the same problem with that - The GridViewRowPresenter is not very adjustable ...